# Query multiple options attributes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have created a search form, But I need some help in how to query the data and results:

Basically, I have a list of products, and in each product there is one `product_type` and also each product can have many materials attributes.

I already made the query to get the type of products, and that is easy since the `product type id` is in the same table (products) but than I have to filter the products with the materials (attributes) selected by the user.

My controller:

```
public function searchResults(Request $request)
    {

    if($request->has('type')){
        $type =  $request->type;
    }
    if($request->has('material')){
        $material = $request->material;
    }

    $query = \DB::table('products');

    //only one type             
   if ($request->has('type') && $type) {
        $query->where('product_type_id', $type);
    }

    // multiple values
    if ($request->has('material') && $material) {
//create query to get all the products with the materials selected
// the materials request comes in a array of ids ([1,2,3])..
    }

    $products = $query->get();

    return view('catalogs.index',compact('products'));

    }
}
```

Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class, 'product_id','id');
    }

    public function businessAreaName()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductBusinessarea::class,'id','product_businessarea_id');
    }

    public function typeName()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(ProductType::class,'id','product_type_id');
    }

    public function businessAttributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttributeBusinessarea::class);
    }

    public function materialAttributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttributeMaterial::class);
    }

    public function areas(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductAttributeBusinessarea::class);
    }
    public function materials(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductAttributeMaterial::class);
    }
}
```

DATABASE:

**products**

- id
- name
- type_id

**product_attribute_materials**

- product_id
- product_material_id

**product_materials**

- id
- name

How I can combine the query to get all the products with the materials selected ?

Comment: Can you add your Eloquent model with its relationships ?

Comment: yes i believe i can, but how i would make this combination? I need to pass the materials parameters, how i would do in in the model of Product?

Comment: @OuailB means can you show your Eloquent model code and add it to the question !!

Comment: sorry, i just added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Join tables,

```
$query = DB::table('products')
->join("product_attribute_materials","products.id","=","product_attribute_materials.product_id")
->whereIn("product_attribute_materials.product_material_id", $material)
->get();
```

OR

U can get first product ID's from the "product_attribute_materials" (table) and then get products  from the product table.
like,

```
$material = DB :: table("product_attribute_materials")
->pluck('product_id')
->whereIn("product_material_id", $material)->toArray();

$query->whereIn('id', $material);
```

i hope it helps.